# Google using OAuth 2.0 Issue in Content API for Shopping

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api

I am trying to get the JSON data of this URI provided by google:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/content/v2/merchantId/productstatuses/productId

I provided the merchant ID as well as the product ID and I got the OAuth activated by toggling the OAuth2.0.

I always get the error when I click the button Execute. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I have gone through API Manager and set up OAuth 2.0 client IDs but still not working. Am I missing something? Please take me to the right track. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the answer, it was because it requires me to have a Google Merchant center account and only have Google Payment Merchant Center account.